# VBA Copy, paste, and transpose data from one workbook to other workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I used this code from ADO to copy paste data between workbook. The data from first workbook is vertical. I want to copy it and paste to other workbook in horizontal position. How can I do it with the code below? Thanks in advance

```
Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long
' Create the connection string.
If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;"";"
    End If
Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    End If
End If

If SourceSheet = "" Then
    ' workbook level name
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    ' worksheet level name or range
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then

    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData

    Else
        'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
            Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
End If

' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Check this: [Copy Data Between Excel Sheets using VBA](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1187802/Copy-Data-Between-Excel-Sheets-using-VBA) If you want to transorm data, you have 2 options: 1) using [MS Access SQL Transform statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx) or using 2) Excel [Transpose method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheetfunction-transpose-method-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getrows! getrows method get data  from recordset transposed type.

Dim vDB

vDB= rsData.getRows

TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).resize(ubound (vDB,1)+1,Ubound (vDB,2)+1)=vDB

getRows Function  get data of recordset as Array, but transposed.
So,  the array like this

vDB(0,0), vDB(0,1),....,vDB(0,n)

vdb(1,0), vdb(1,1),....,vDB(1,n)

....

vDB(c,0), vDB(c,1), ...,vDB(c,n)

At this Example,  n+1 is recordcount, c+1 is Fieldscount.
It is also equeals  Ubound(vdb,2)+1, Ubound(vDB,1)+1 .

This is All code.

```
Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long
' Create the connection string.
If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;"";"
    End If
Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    End If
End If

If SourceSheet = "" Then
    ' workbook level name
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    ' worksheet level name or range
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    Dim vDB
    vDB = rsData.getRows
    If Header = False Then
        'TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1) + 1, UBound(vDB, 2) + 1) = vDB
    Else
        'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1 + lCount, 1).Value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
            Next lCount
            'TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1) + 1, UBound(vDB, 2) + 1) = vDB
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1) + 1, UBound(vDB, 2) + 1) = vDB
        End If
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
End If

' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub
SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this general routine to transpose a Range:

```
Sub TransposeRange(r As Range)
    Dim ar: ar = Application.Transpose(r.Value2)
    r.ClearContents
    r.Resize(r.Columns.Count, r.Rows.Count).value = ar
End Sub
```

To call it from your code, you can add this before the line `rsData.Close`:

```
TransposeRange(TargetRange.Resize(rsData.RecordCount, rsData.Fields.Count))
```

The method `RecordCount` of the `Recordset` object is often vexing. We can overcome it by guessing the number of copied records differently. Two methods are possible:

1- Memorise the number of fecthed records returned by `CopyFromRecordset`

2- As a "lazy fix", get the number of copied rows from the range:

```
TransposeRange(TargetRange.Resize(TargetRange.End(xlDown).Row + 1 -TargetRange.Row, _
  rsData.Fields.Count))
```

**Finally**, beware that excel has much more room for rows than for columns. If your data has more records than can fit in the number of columns, the operation is impossible.

Comment: @AdryanPermana `RecordCount` is very often vexing. Try any of the alternative methods added to my answer.