# Is it possible to do SQL lookup from one Excel sheet to another using VBA when table is horizontal?

Tags: vba, excel

This is a rather odd question, but it's been in my mind for a while.
Say for example I have an Excel sheet with a table:

```
__________________________
| ID       |Name         |
|----------|-------------|
|00001     |Adam         |
|----------|-------------|
|00002     |James        |
|__________|_____________|
```

I can get the data from that table and transfer it to another worksheet using VBA and including an SQL statement with it.
The question now is what if the table is created horizontally?

```
___________________________
|ID    |00001   |00002    |
|------|--------|---------|
|Name  |Adam    |James    |
|______|________|_________|
```

The header is located on the horizontal axis. Is there a way so that the SQL can read the data like this?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You need to transpose the data first.

Comment: getRows  method , it is possible.

Comment: Why do you need to use SQL for this? Is there some restraint against WorksheetFunctions? Also can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Of course worksheet functions such as Vlookup or any other formulas can work. Its just that the project I'm doing requires both worksheets to be in separate instances, so the worksheet functions wouldn't work because they aren't connected. However with SQL in VBA it can connect as long as both sheets are open. At least from my limited experience.

Comment: Separate instances as in separate workbooks? Presumably same computer?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622896/vba-copy-paste-and-transpose-data-from-one-workbook-to-other-workbook/44629153#44629153) is getRows method.  You can use transpose method.

Comment: yes. separate workbooks in same computer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just excel formula, you can use HLOOKUP. Which is a VLOOKUP but Horizontal.